# Authenticate Videos for logged in users only

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, video, video-streaming

I have a div that plays a given video in it. Here is the HTML code

```
    <video id="tutorial_video" width="100%" height="100%">
       <source src='videoURL' type='video/mp4'>
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

What I want is not to set the URL in the src as this will allow anyone to take and share the link and I want to prevent this. Only Authorized users will be able to play the video and not anyone with the link.

Is there a way to prevent anyone with the link to play the video ? maybe I make the video URL changes each time (How can I do this)? Is there a simpler way ?

Edit 1:

I made the authentication using action-controller method that validate first the user is logged in (more details [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=998)). It did work, but a second problem appears, if the user logs in, he/she can download the video by just copying the link (from the source of the video tag) into the browser. Is there a way to fix this ?

Edit 2:

It finally works fine. I changed the content type (in that previous link) from "attachment" to "video/mp4" as follows:

```
 context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "video/mp4; filename=test.mp4");
```

Thanks to @kspearrin

Comment: You could stream the video file through a controller action rather than serving it directly from disk. Then you can validate the user or redirect them to login.

Comment: I just used that and it did work but, it made the user able to download the video if the user just logged in and pasted the url of that controller action link in the browser.

Comment: You should be able to adjust the content type to stop it from downloading and actually stream.

Comment: that works out ! Thanks a lot (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply stream the video over a controller action instead of direct linking the file from disk. This will give you the ability to control access and authenticate the request.

You can follow [this link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=998) to achieve that (just add on it an authentication that the user is logged in)

Be sure to lock down the file on disk so that it can only be accessed through the action and not by someone guessing the file name.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797297/how-to-restrict-access-to-a-certain-file-in-mvc) is one way to lock the file down

Comment: Another way to lock down the file would be to use a file storage like AWS S3 or Azure Blob Storage. These storage systems give you the ability to lock down public access but still deliver the file over an authenticated SDK.